# SQL error syntax on query with variables

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create an import script that looks as below:

```
foreach ( $app_files as $file ) {
            if ( $row["old_id_import"] == $file['idx'] ) {

                $ids   = $row["id"];
                $files = $file['file'];
                $date  = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' );
                $sql2  = "INSERT INTO palace_files ('id', 'module', 'item_id', 'name', 'status', 'date', 'modified') VALUES (NULL, 5, "'.$ids.'", "'.$files.'",1 ,"'.$date.'" , "'.$date.'")";
                if ($conn->query($sql2) === TRUE) {
                    echo "New record imported successfully";
                } else {
                    echo "Error: " . $sql2 . "<br>" . $conn->error;
                }
            }
        }
```

But it seems that i have syntax error, dont know where. Maybe i am tired.

**I have found similar threads but none worked.**

Comment: What does `echo $sql2` show?

Comment: output the sql command to check if it`s correct.

Comment: example INSERT INTO palace_files ('id', 'module', 'item_id', 'name', 'status', 'date', 'modified') VALUES (NULL, 5, 1357, 143099797075.830,1 ,2017-07-26 22:41:10 , 2017-07-26 22:41:10 )

Comment: Backticks (`\``), not quotes (`'`) for table/column names.... quotes are used for string literals

Comment: Now learn to use prepared statements with bind variables, and enter the 21st century

Comment: You're using the wrong type of identifier qualifiers https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-qualifiers.html and is the main reason why your code failed. Then your quoting's inverted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You query has some mistakes/could be improved.

1. status and date are keywords in sql. In order for them to be future proof (in case they become reserved, or new ones are added), or you want to always safely use any column name you want and not worry about if they could cause errors, better just wrap them in backticks ``
2. you should not wrap the columns in ' '
3. you are not wrapping them with ' ' in your values

Your query should read as follows:

```
$sql2 = "INSERT INTO palace_files (id, module, item_id, name, status, date, modified) 
         VALUES (NULL, 5, '{$ids}', '{$files}',1 ,'{$date}' , '{$date}')";
```

Comment: Why is the code snippet in my answer not showing as code?? And why the down vote?

Comment: I have use date,status, name as entity name in  my database and that has no problem. so that is not the reason for his error

Comment: But it could happen and it is bad practice not to do so, so i am advising to wrap them in case anyone else comes across this post... 2. and 3. should solve your problem

Comment: if you wrap in ' ' without the { } or . . sign php will see it a just string @'$ids', '$files',1 ,'$date' , '$date')  it has to be in '{$ids}'

Comment: You don't _need_ to do that. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php) for example. But i have added it in my answer.

Comment: *"module, status and date are reserved words in sql"* - Where did you get that information from? @Yolo

Comment: @Fred-ii- See [reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html). Although module is not listed, my IDE was marking it as such. I changed that in my answer.

Comment: @Yolo I know it quite well and none of those are listed in there or in any RDBMS.

Comment: @Yolo `DATE` and `STATUS` are keywords, not reserved. These are two different animals altogether. Notice there are no `(R)`'s next to them. So there's no need to tick them.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I have improved my answer based on your last comment.

Comment: Thank you @Yolo that's more true to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Your are doing wrong concatination. See somehere you missed `.` operator & quote `"`. Inside `""` you can use php variable it will interpret its value.

```
 $sql2  = "INSERT INTO palace_files ('id', 'module', 'item_id', 'name', 'status', 'date', 'modified') VALUES (NULL, 5, "'.$ids.'", "'.$files.'",1 ,"'.$date.'" , "'.$date.'")";
```

Try this:

```
foreach ($app_files as $file) {
 if ($row["old_id_import"] == $file['idx']) {

    $ids = $row["id"];
    $files = $file['file'];
    $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $sql2 = "INSERT INTO palace_files (id, module, item_id, name, status, date, modified) VALUES (NULL, 5, '$ids', '$files',1 ,'$date' , '$date')";
    if ($conn->query($sql2) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record imported successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql2 . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: This answer is completely incorrect and it needs to be fixed.

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanks i have fixed now

Comment: `('id', 'module', 'item_id', 'name', 'status', 'date', 'modified')` there shouldn't be quotes for these `'` - they either need to be removed, or using what are called ticks `\`` which resemble quotes, but are different.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($app_files as $file) {
 if ($row["old_id_import"] === $file['idx']) {

    $ids = $row["id"];
    $files = $file['file'];
    $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $sql2 = "INSERT INTO palace_files (module, item_id, name, status, date, modified) VALUES (5, '{$ids}', '{$files}',1 ,'{$date}' , '{$date}')";
    if ($conn->query($sql2) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record imported successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql2 . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
 }
}
```

Instead of inserting ID why not set ID as auto-increment and allow it take care of itself